# Python attrs nested objects convertes

Tags: python, python-attrs

I'm using `attrs` lib to parse my configuration file, and I'm looking for a better way to parse nested data objects.

Example :

```
from attrs import define, field, validators
from typing import Dict

class HoconParser:
    @classmethod
    def from_hocon(cls, file_path):
        from pyhocon import ConfigFactory

        return cls(
            **ConfigFactory.parse_file(file_path)
        )
    
    @classmethod
    def from_dictstrobj(cls, dictstrobj):
        
        if dictstrobj:
            return {
                key: cls(**value) for key, value in dictstrobj.items()
            }
        return {}
@define
class ClassOne(HoconParser):
    id: str = field(validator=validators.instance_of(str))
    name: str = field(validator=validators.instance_of(str))
    
@define
class ClassTwo(HoconParser):
    id: str = field(validator=validators.instance_of(str))
    name: str = field(validator=validators.instance_of(str))
    test: Dict[str, ClassOne] = field(
        converter=ClassOne.from_dictstrobj,
        validator=validators.deep_mapping(
            key_validator=validators.instance_of(str),
            value_validator=validators.instance_of(ClassOne)
        )
    )
    
a = ClassTwo.from_hocon("test.conf")
```

Basically, ClassTwo has an attribute which is a `Dict[str, ClassOne]`.

In order to make this work, I had to make a specific function named `from_dictstrobj` and use it as a converter for `test` attribute.

Is there any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a major contributor to *attrs* and the author of *cattrs*.

You might want to use the [*cattrs*](https://catt.rs/en/stable/) library here. I'm assuming `ConfigFactory.parse_file(file_path)` produces a dictionary?

*cattrs* can recursively transform this dictionary into a graph of objects.

Here's the modified code:

```py
from cattrs import structure

class HoconParser:
    @classmethod
    def from_hocon(cls, file_path):
        from pyhocon import ConfigFactory

        return structure(ConfigFactory.parse_file(file_path), cls)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank alot ! One last question how do you references "self" in an attribute definition ? For example, is my class `ClassOne` had an attribute named `test_self` which needs to be of type `ClassOne` ?

Comment: Ah, that would be a recursive type. You should stringify the annotation. Also I think you'd have to make the type `ClassOne | None`, otherwise it'd be infinitely recursive.
```
from attrs import define

from cattrs import structure


@define
class ClassOne:
    test_self: "ClassOne | None" = None


print(structure({"test_self": {"test_self": None}}, ClassOne))
```